# What is the good practice to keep multiple html having the same style and components but different in certain body content

Tags: html, django

new to web dev here. I am wondering what is the common practice to have multiple pages with the same components (header, sidebar, footer) but only different in the content. I looked around there are suggestion about using php include and other about html import.

Say I have a `basic.html` with

```
<head> fixed stuff </head>
<body>
<div> sidebar here </div>

<!-- Here will be different content other each page -->

<footer> fixed stuff </footer>

<!-- common scripts here -->
</body>
```

Then I will have another 2 pages, say `price.html, blog.html`.

How can price.html recycle `basic.html` but just with different main contents in the body. I don't know how I can use include here. because the content is in the middle.

Comment: Templates or partials. Depends on what server technology, etc, you're using.

Comment: There isn't much you can do with plain HTML, apart from sharing the same CSS style-sheets (you're using CSS, right?). Even a static site generator requires a programming language. Back in the late 1990s you could have used frames ;-)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I am using Django, and load html through a template folder. If that answer your question. Thanks

Comment: Tagging this question with only `html` makes it very broad. The modern-day approach is to dynamically generate your html, and there are many different tools for this.

Comment: Now I'm confused. You use Django to craft dynamically generated HTML and you're researching PHP to... do the same?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález No I wasn't actively seeking a php solution. It was just I find a post about using php. I am afraid I don't have enough knowledge to know what is appropriate .

Answer (score 0):

I would do basic.php and create header.php, footer.php. Then you can do includes on your page templates that would include the header and footer file. Then you can construct your price template...price.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<?php include(header.php); ?>
// Price template content
<?php include(footer.php); ?>
</html>
```

Is that what you are trying to accomplish? This will allow you to add your header and footer content that is universal for your site and make different middle content depending on your page.